# Can a Second Const Reference Extend the Lifetime of a Temporary

Tags: c++, temporary-objects, const-reference, prvalue

- Background:

I noticed that the signature of std::max is:

**template<typename T>

const T& max(const T&, const T&);**

and I wondered about the implications of returning a reference to a const
T...

If we pass in two L-values, it makes sense we could return a reference to
one of the two. But if we pass in two PR-values, what is being returned and
is it a safe thing to use?

## Problem:

I spoke with some colleagues and here is a minimal working example of the
issue: http://cpp.sh/4en4

```
#include <iostream>
int glob = 100;
class temp{
  int* val;
public:
  temp(int n = 0){
    val = new int(n);
  }
  void print() const{ std::cout << "I store " << *val << std::endl; }
  ~temp(){
    std::cout << "temp object died" << std::endl;
    delete val;
    val = &glob;
  }
};
const temp& foo(const temp& a){
  return a;    
}

int main(){
  const temp& b = foo(2); 
  std::cout << "Is it safe?" << std::endl;
  b.print(); 
}
```

Without optimization:

```
temp object died
Is it safe?
I store 100
```

With moderate:

```
temp object died
Is it safe?
I store -1992206527
```

Running this with different levels of optimization gives different
results. In all cases, though, it seems that returning the reference does
not prolong the lifetime of the local object; its desctructor is still
called, although in one case we seem to recover a reference to the
destroyed object and in the other, we seem to have a dangling pointer.

## The Standard:

Quoting from the C++ Standard, document number N4618:

> 12.2 item 6:
>
> ... when a reference is bound to a temporary. The temporary to which the
>   reference is
>   bound or the temporary that is the complete object of a subobject to which
>   the reference is bound persists
>   for the lifetime of the reference except: 
>   (6.1) — A temporary object bound to a reference parameter in a function
>   call (5.2.2) persists until the completion
>   of the full-expression containing the call. 
>   (6.2) — The lifetime of a temporary bound to the returned value in a
>   function return statement (6.6.3) is not
>   extended; the temporary is destroyed at the end of the full-expression in
>   the return statement."

From (6.1), it would seem a temporary foo(2) should exist for the entire
statement that initializes b.

From (6.2), it would seem that the local 'a' gets destroyed, which
actually destroys the temporary foo(2), resulting in b taking on a
destructed value.

## My Questions:

1a. What is the full-expression that contains the temporary generated by
`foo(2)` in `const temp& b = foo(2);`

1b. Can a 2nd const reference extend the lifetime of a temporary?

2. Why is std::max implemented as such, given the apparent danger?

Comment: Post code here.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13721839/if-stdmax-returns-by-reference-as-it-must-might-that-lead-to-a-dangling-r

Comment: @JRG: thanks for that link. So it seems this is a dangling pointer. I'd still like to understand this in the context of (6.1) and (6.2) in the Standard and the question 1a. What is the "full-expression" here?

Comment: @NeilButterworth the code is in the URL right below the "Problem" bullet point.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6059134/464289

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++: Life span of temporary arguments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506793/c-life-span-of-temporary-arguments)

Comment: Post code here inline with your question, not via a link.

Comment: @NeilButterworth code is now included at the end of the post

Comment: Lifetime of temporary is only extended when a reference is bound to a prvalue.