# Is it possible to create a better version of `std::min` & `std::max`?

Tags: c++, c++17

With the new features of C++17, is it possible to create a better `std::min` and `std::max`?

What I mean by better:

- `std::min/max` has the problem of [dangling references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13721839/if-stdmax-returns-by-reference-as-it-must-might-that-lead-to-a-dangling-r).
- `std::min/max` doesn't work with different types (i.e., `min(short, int)` needs to explicitly specify the type `min<int>(...)`)

I'd like to have a better implementation, which:

- avoids the dangling reference problem (for example, `min(a, 4);`  works correctly)
- works with different types (for example, `min((short)4, (int)8);` compiles)
- avoids unnecessary object copies (for example, if I have a class which represents a big integer, it only copies it when it is unavoidable)

Is it possible to do this, or is `std::min/max` the current best solution which one can have?

Comment: Anything is possible....

Comment: What answer do you expect? "Yes" is a bit short, "yes here it is" is too broad. For the right definition of "better" you can surely find a better version.

Comment: Define better. :-) For example, when used with different types, what type should it return?

Comment: @BoPersson `std::common_type_t` of course.

Comment: -7 for this seems a little aggressive. Does the question really show insufficient research effort, clarity, or usefulness? "Too broad", maybe, but not... -7...

Comment: @BoPersson: yes, it needs some design work, but I don't think that there is too much possibility for that...

Comment: @Barry: I did research this. And haven't found anything, which fulfills my needs. Hence the question.

Comment: @nwp: I expect some implementation which fulfills what I described. If it is too broad, can you please tell, which part is too broad? We're talking about a thing, which should be dead simple, `min`.

Comment: That's even worse. "Here are the requirements. Write the code for me". SO typically doesn't like those "questions". Normally you just attempt to implement it, get stuck and ask about a specific issue. Or you succeed and post it on codereview.so. This is just lazy.

Comment: @nwp: it is not "for me". It is for everyone. That's a huge difference. A better min/max would be good for everyone, not just me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an old and failed proposal for a better `min`/`max` using just C++11 tech:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2199.html

Comment: Any color on the failure? Viewed as harmful or simply insufficiently beneficial?

Comment: The comment at the time was that the implementation was embarrassingly complicated.  For a while this paper was actually the butt of jokes.  Since then, ironically, parts of the implementation have actually been standardized.  E.g. `promote` is now `std::common_type`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Why is it a problem, if it is complicated? If it does the job well...

Comment: I wish you had been in that room a decade ago to ask that question! :-)

Comment: :) To be honest, I don't find this complicated at all. Yes, it seems that it is much code, but it is not. C++ is just very verbose for these kind of tasks.

Comment: I need to restructure this a little bit, so this can be used for used types as well (the `promote` template need to be specialized).

Comment: I recommend subbing in `std::common_type` for `promote`, which also allows specialization on user-defined types.