# Why is volatile not compiling with std::min

Tags: c++, gcc, volatile

Why is following code not compilable (gcc-5.4.0)?

```
volatile int i{100};
int j{200};
std::cout << std::min(i, j);
```

I mean I see the compiler error:

> error: no matching function for call to ‘min(volatile int&, int&)’

Isn't volatile just hint to compiler, that the variable could change from outside of the program?

```
std::min(int(i), j);
```

Is of course working. But shouldn't original work too?

Comment: It's worth pointing out that volatile is one of the most mis-understood keywords in the c++ language... and that you should be sure you need it before you use it (not suggesting that you don't need it in your case, there's not enough information - just putting in a word of warning).

Comment: You know that volatile has nothing to do with threads?

Comment: @UKMonkey: Indeed. When I was young and naughty I'd use it to distinguish parameters when overloading functions. My wrist still hurts from the code reviews.

Comment: @Bathsheba you and StoryTeller were talking about vomiting ... my turn

Comment: Just another c++ standard library design mistake! As pathetical as libc.

Comment: @Oliv: the problem is not it is a design mistake. The problem is that they don't fix it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47398177/8157187

Comment: @Oliv - `std::min` returns a reference to the result. There is no way to do that and have different parameter types.

Comment: Howard should restart a new library! Long live the Howard! (it's own ward!)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`volatile` is a *qualifier* just like `const`. It's more than a mere hint to the compiler.

`std::min` expects the two parameters to have exactly the same types and qualifiers. So in your case it issues a diagnostic.

Since you are allowed to *introduce* qualifiers, you could indulge in a little hand-holding and write

```
std::min<volatile int>(i, j)
```

Answer (score 12):

As @Bathsheba pointed out, type deduction on the two arguments must give the same type.

But for the sake of completeness `std::min` is also overloaded to accept a `std::initializer_list`. The elements of it are subject to copy initialization, so top level cv-qualifiers are immaterial. So this will work:

```
std::cout << std::min({i, j});
```

Just bear in mind that it performs copies, and doesn't accept or return references.

Comment: Also note that `std::min<int>(i, j)` would still cause the compiler to puke, so it's a little deeper than template deduction needing its hand holding.

Comment: @Bathsheba - `std::min<volatile int>` would work on the other hand. Though it makes *me* puke.

Comment: Indeed it would! I like littering my answers with those kind of nuggets. In it goes.

Comment: _"top level cv-qualifiers are immaterial"_ is it a quote or poetic licence?

Comment: @Bathsheba "those kinds of nuggets" - to make storyteller puke, post `std::min<volatile int>(a, b)` ... any other nuggets like this?

Comment: @YSC - Poetic license without question. The day the standard will ever consider qualifiers truly immaterial it's the time to move onto D.

Comment: @UKMonkey - There's always the good old `Foo *f = new Foo; f->do_operation(); delete f;` Students and recovering Java programmers are particularly fond of that one.

Comment: @StoryTeller my new mission for today - find an answer I can "reasonably" answer with that

Comment: @UKMonkey Perhaps something where a `Foo` is too large for the stack (though that in itself would be a sign of a problem).