# Could C++ concepts be used to implement mixed type min and max in C++?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

As you may know `std::max` and `std::min` "suffer" from the fact they have 1 template argument, so even simple `max(container.size(), 47)` will not work since .size() returns `size_t` and 47 is `int`.

I know there was historically [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2199.html) to add proper overloads to C++ but it was rejected.
But from what I know it was mostly due to paper being too complex for not enough gain, so I wonder if one would use `std::common_range_t` as return value (invented type trait that gives you int/float big enough to hold the min/max of mixed arguments, else hard error) would that be fine...

So to finally get to my question:
If we want min/max extended to take 2 template arguments as described above are there any backward compatibility or any other issues that prevent that?

note:

- This is mostly is it technically possible question, I am **not** interested if WG21 plans to do anything to standardize this, mostly curious about potential technical limitations.
- [C++17 version of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47397997/is-it-possible-to-create-a-better-version-of-stdmin-stdmax)(for some reason heavily downvoted ), but more general, also deals with some other limitations.

Comment: Aren't you actually asking whether "C++ Concepts" would make it easier to implement `common_range_t` ?  Do you think that `min`/`max` are somehow different from any other potential user of `common_range_t`?  If so, please explain in what way they are special.

Comment: I don't know what you're asking. The title is talking about concepts, the content is talking about backwards compatibility of that paper. Also, I'm not sure why you think your `std::common_range_t` would differ from what's in the paper (note that some of the complexity comes from the paper predating `std::common_type`)?

Comment: @Barry yeah, it was clear in my head... what I meant is that common_range_t would require that types are "close enough", maybe if I used constraint in title that would be clearer?

Comment: @BenVoigt I am just curious if there is some backward comparability issue, if I have my_lib::max I can do what I want since I control all the users

Answer (score 5):

The two-argument `std::min/max` return *references* to the parameter that is the min/max. That requires that they be of the same type, since you can't have a function return different types. Nor can you return a reference to a temporary.

The only way to do this is to create a new function that returns a value (probably of type `std::common_type`), a copy of the min/max. But since it returns a copy rather than a reference, it would not be backwards compatible with `std::min/max`.

Comment: "since you can't have a function return different types." that sucks, I thought that concepts will solve that ambiguity, let me godbolt that, I am saddened by this discovery...

Comment: One could presumably have the existing signature (returning a reference) and the new mixed-type one as a fallback that kicks in only when arguments fail to bind as references in the existing signature.

Comment: @BenVoigt I think so, issue is that common_type is not working as expected, but it is not an issue, it could be fixed by using some other type trait(I think for uint32 and int32 it return int32), or fixing a bug in my code :)  https://godbolt.org/z/oMGjnz6EW

Comment: less bad godbolt example: https://godbolt.org/z/Gd7eheYas

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: Backwards-compatibility demands one more overload to support the existing non-const reference signature, but your pattern worked great: https://godbolt.org/z/qnnsfPG1E

Comment: @BenVoigt cool, but std::common_type is bad for this usecase, right, it can not handle (2u,-1) case...

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl Yeah you need a template helper that really implements widening instead of simply using the C++ type promotion ranking, which thinks `int` -> `unsigned` is a widening conversion.